# A docker container on Debian running code compiled for an ARM processor

Tags: docker, x86, dockerfile, arm, docker-machine

I am very new to Docker.

I have developed applications in C code which are cross-compiled and run on an embedded Linux device which uses an ARM chip. My toolchain and build process is well defined.

A new task of mine is to get these applications into Docker containers to run independently inside a bigger Linux device which uses an X86 processor.

Now, i'm confused. Can I just compile my code in the same way as before using the ARM toolchain and instruct Docker that the executables are for ARM and not X86? I have heard about Multi-Arch images, but not too sure. Thanks

Comment: If the final execution environment is x86, then wouldn't you need x86 and not ARM binaries?  Docker can't execute wrong-architecture binaries usually.  I might look at "configure the build chain for the correct architecture" and "package the result in Docker" as two independent tasks.

Comment: @DavidMaze The problem is i'm trying to generate a Docker image that can run on various host architectures.. X86, ARM etc. I guess it's not so straight forward however. ?

Comment: Since a Docker image generally contains the base OS and tools, and things like `/bin/sh` will be built for a single architecture, you'll probably need to cross-build a separate image for each target platform.  @ddegasperi's answer, plus your existing cross-compilation tool chain, should get you there.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the multi-arch builds by adding a build argument. For example:

`docker build -t org/yourapp:arm32v7 --build-arg ARCH=arm32v7/ .`

A easier way to build the image for all required platforms with one cli instruction is to use the experimental build engine buildx. See also instructions on the [docker blog](https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-arch-build-and-images-the-simple-way/)